# I can't deploy my rails app via mina deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, mina

I'm trying deploy a Rails App (5.2.0 and Ruby 2.4.0) to a server (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS) via mina deploy. I already configured my files to deploy, but when I try run `mina deploy`, I get the error: `bash: line 145: bundle: command not found`. Like this:

```
mina deploy
-----> Creating a temporary build path
-----> Using RVM environment "ruby-2.4.0@marconPortfolio"
       Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0 with gemset marconPortfolio
-----> Deploying marconPortfolio to 165.227.63.110:/home/rails/marcon
-----> Fetching new git commits
       remote: Counting objects: 8, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
       remote: Total 8 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (8/8), done.   
       From bitbucket.org:felipeemarcon/marcon-portfolio
          6113173..1f02042  master     -> master
-----> Using git branch 'master'
       Cloning into '.'...
       done.
-----> Using this git commit
       Felipe Marcon (1f02042):
       > Rvm path in deploy
-----> Symlinking shared paths
-----> Installing gem dependencies using Bundler
       bash: line 145: bundle: command not found
 !     ERROR: Deploy failed.
-----> Cleaning up build
       Unlinking current
       OK
       Connection to 165.227.63.110 closed.

 !     Run Error
```

I've already search in to many places how fix this, but nothing helped. How can i solve this?

I already run "gem install bundle" in my server and when I run "bundle --version" it returns the version of bundler, so it's installed. The ruby version in my server is the same that I have in local (ruby 2.4.0). I don't know what to do to solve this. Anyone can help me?

Oh, if that's relevant, I'm using Puma as the app server.

deploy.rb

```
require 'mina/bundler'
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/git'
require 'mina/rvm'
require 'mina/puma'

set :domain, '165.227.63.110'

set :deploy_to, '/home/rails/marcon'

set :repository, 'git@bitbucket.org:felipeemarcon/marcon-portfolio.git'

set :branch, 'master'

set :shared_dirs, fetch(:shared_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/uploads')
set :shared_files, fetch(:shared_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'config/puma.rb')

set :user, 'root'

set :application_name, 'marconPortfolio'
set :ssh_flags, '-l root'
set :rvm_use_path, '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm'


task :remote_environment do
  invoke :'rvm:use', 'ruby-2.4.0@marconPortfolio'
end

task :setup do
  command %[touch "#{fetch(:shared_path)}/config/database.yml"]
  command %[touch "#{fetch(:shared_path)}/config/secrets.yml"]
  command %[touch "#{fetch(:shared_path)}/config/puma.rb"]
  comment "Be sure to edit '#{fetch(:shared_path)}/config/database.yml', 'secrets.yml' and puma.rb."
end

task :deploy do
  deploy do
    comment "Deploying #{fetch(:application_name)} to #{fetch(:domain)}:#{fetch(:deploy_to)}"
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    # invoke :'rvm:load_env_vars'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    command %{#{fetch(:rails)} db:seed}
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    invoke :'deploy:cleanup'

    on :launch do
      command "export RAILS_ENV=production"
      invoke :'puma:phased_restart'
      command '/etc/init.d/nginx restart'
      command 'rm -f /home/rails/marcon/current/public/system/'
      command "ln -s /home/rails/marcon/current/public/"
    end
  end
end
```

puma.rb:

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count

port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

plugin :tmp_restart

bind "unix:/home/rails/marcon/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock" if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") == 'production'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solve this problem. I clone my project directly to my server, install the dependencies and after, I runed mina deploy from my local machine. Now everything works fine.

But I still guess that should not work like this. I should not be able to deploy my application in the first time by `mina deploy` in the server?

Thank you all.

Comment: Where did you clone the project to on your server? In the mina setup directory structure or just anywhere? I did the same by cloning it to my home directory and executing bundle install. This installed all the gems, but unfortunately I'm still getting the bundler error when deploying via mina.

Comment: I cloned into mina setup directory. For example, /home/app (the same directory in deploy.rb). In my case the first deploy with mina doesn't worked. Did you run mina init and mina setup? What bundler error you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try running {sudo gem install bundler} And then try to deploy.
And if that doesn't work then maybe you need to add the ruby gem executable directory to your path.

Comment: If I try with sudo, it returns `sudo: gem: command not found`. It only install if i run `gem install bundler`, but it's already installed.

How I add the ruby gem executable directory to my path?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you in your project directory while running this command?

Comment: I added a new answer below. Thanks.